# How do I make the ListView clickable and show some text once it gets clicked?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-listview, android-adapter

I am practicing ListView and I have placed a few List Items on an activity. Right now I have 3 items of list (in three rows). I want that once a user click one of the row (let's say it's my first row for now) s/he should be able to see some details text about it. That text will be displayed somewhere at at the bottom of the activity , outside the ListView.How could I do that?
Like this:

[image: Example here]

I am working on this code:

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String[] list = {"About Company", "Home Page", "Contact"};

        Adapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listId);

        listView.setAdapter((ListAdapter) adapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(

                new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        String listPosition = String.valueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
                        /*after clicking the first row of the list show the following info :
                        NAME: Some name
                        ADDRESS: Somewhere
                         */
                    }
                }
        );


    }
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
    <ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/listId"

    android:background="#f79727"
    android:textFilterEnabled="false"
    android:layout_marginBottom="300dp" />

<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/listId"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="66dp" />
```

Comment: Define your layout. You'd probably want to replace the second `ListView` with some views displaying info, like some `TextView`s. That done, you can refresh these views into the `OnItemClickListener` you set up.

Comment: Why you have used two listviews?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need good code working samples and a tutorial. A good link is [Using an ArrayAdapter with ListView][1]

[1]: https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView . 
You asked to populate the **Listview**, look at the code extending the **ArrayAdapter**.
Since you want to write text on the bottom, you can create a TextView outside the **LinearLayout** in the res/layout/**item_user.xml**. That is one simple way. Try some code and see what you get. You'll have to participate half way since you can learn a lot here.

Answer (score 0):

Add an onClickListener on the list view.  When clicked set the text below.

Comment: Graeme, I know how to make the button clicked, but i dont know how and where to define and set the text I want to display.

Comment: Riyana has used a correct way on item click listener

Answer (score 0):

Try this

XML

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/listId"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="66dp"

    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"

 />
```

CLick Listener ListView

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position,
                    long id) {
                 String listPosition = list[position];
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity .this, listPosition , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Jorge Moreno, not exactly that I wanted. because after clicking the list it should display some specific text: for example: "Name of the company: Volvo; Address: Some address". But right now with ur suggestion it will only gets the value from the current index and show that as text.

Comment: Riyana wants to display the text as label. Here toast will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Change you code to the following

```
String[] descriptionList = {"Company's Address....", "Home Address....", "Contact no...."};
```

Your XML file content

```
<ListView android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:id="@+id/listId"
 android:background="#f79727"
 android:textFilterEnabled="false"
 android:layout_marginBottom="300dp" />

    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textview" android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/listId"
 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
 android:layout_marginBottom="66dp" />
```

initialize the textview in oncreate() method

```
textView =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview);
```

Your ontemclick listener

```
 listView.setOnItemClickListener( new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) { 
   textView.setText(descriptionList.get(position));
    } } );
```

Comment: Fahim, thank u, but where do I store or define the text I want to display. From this line of code: textView.setText(listPosition); it only shows the name of the list that was stored in listPosition. what if I want to show customized text?

Comment: u dont have to define it, it will pickup from adapter as shown in the code. just initialize the textview in the oncreate() method to use it in onitemclick method. Hope you understood

Comment: Fahim, without defining how do i get my default text? coz its not stored anywhere?

Comment: Fahim, may be u still have misunderstanding. its great that u took step to help me out. but what I want is when a user click on the list ,the textView area will display some defaults text: this default text will be the text that I want to choose by my own. Ok, here is what i want:  STEP 1: Click on the first list; STEP 2: display the following text: "Name: Sony; Address: USA". How do i display that text? that means after clicking on the list that piece of text should appear!

Comment: ok.. you will having list of text content for each listview position right

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71254/discussion-between-fahim-and-riyana).