# Android how to detect second click in setOnItemClickListener

Tags: android, listview, onitemclicklistener

I manage to do there is a `ListView` which contains the `TextView`. if click on the `TextView` it will show the `ImageButton`, else the second click the `ImageButton` in the `ListView` will hide. My problem is I can only show the `ImageButton` for the first click but I can't hide `ImageButton` when I clicked on `TextView` again. Any suggestion to solve this problem.

this is my listview `setontimeclicklistener`

```
condimentlist.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                      TextView condimentitem =(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.condcb);
                      String citem= condimentitem.getText().toString();
                      ImageView btntick = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iv_tick);

                           int visibility = btntick.getVisibility();
                           if(visibility == View.VISIBLE)
                           {
                                      btntick.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                            }
                                      else if(visibility == View.GONE)
                            {
                                      btntick.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            }

                            ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
                            data.add(citem);
                            String array[] = data.toArray(new String[0]);
                            for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
                                       remark.append(String.valueOf(array[j]));
                            }

              }
});
```

Comment: The textview and image button suppose in the listView ?

Comment: @JohnJoe yes, textview and image isin listview

Comment: Hey better approach is to save it as a Boolean in your listobject and make it visible or invisible depending on that variable. You can change the variable onclick and call datachangelistener

Comment: Wait! What? If your button visibility is GONE, how can you even click it?

Comment: jus the image button GONE, the listview button control the image button is show or hide

Comment: @WeiMingTang You have to keep track of each click take place at each row in the list-view using some hash map.
At each click check whether that positioned text view is clicked second time or vice versa.

Comment: From the code, it seems like you are clicking the listview instead of the textview inside the listview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will works if the `textView` clicked. But I'm not sure whether this can work since the textView is inside the listView.

```
condimentitem.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(btntick.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
                    btntick.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }else{
                    btntick.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

            }
        });
```

I would suggest you write the `ImageView` and `TextView` inside the `adapter`.

---

**Correct Approach**

Write this in **Adapter** class

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_activity, parent, false);
     .....
    condimentim.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
       @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(btntick.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
                btntick.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }else{
                btntick.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: it is impossible to click invisible/gone button

Comment: @hakim Based on the code, it is `ImageView`, not `button`

Comment: it work, but if i set this in my adapter will i cant get the value when i click on each row value

Comment: you still can get the row value

Comment: how can i get the value by passing adapter?

Comment: No,the value is not passing to adapter. You can write something like this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28596293/5156075).

Comment: sry, i means in my listview there get different value in each row, how can i get the value in my adapter?because currently i use setonitemclick to get the each row value

Comment: Why do you want to pass the value to adapter?

Comment: sry , i means get the value from adapter

Comment: The link I sent you will answer your question. When `ListView` clicked, it will display the text based on its `position`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a boolean to act as a switch for you to flop back and forth with an if statement.

```
boolean isClicked = true;
```

for the first click make it true if it is true then hide ImageButton and for the second click make boolean as false and hide ImageButton

```
if(true) 
ImageBtn.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE)
else
ImageBtn.setVisibility(view.GONE)
```

Comment: This is much better cause the next item over this page will have the same state as the first item. That will be terrible.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this code will work:

```
condimentlist.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            TextView condimentitem = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.condcb);
            String citem = condimentitem.getText().toString();
            ImageView btntick = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iv_tick);
            if (btntick.getVisibility == View.GONE) {
                btntick.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                btntick.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
            data.add(citem);
            String array[] = data.toArray(new String[0]);
            for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
                remark.append(String.valueOf(array[j]));
            }
       }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use **SparseIntArray** to map clicks for each item in your listView

in the adapter, constructor initialize the array as

```
public LVAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<String> data) {
        super(context, resource);
        this.data = data;
        sba = new SparseBooleanArray(data.size());
 }
```

then store the clicks in this array using the position of the item as a key

```
public void onItemClick(...) {
         if(!sba.get(position)) // first click
            sba.put(position,true);
         else{ // second click
             // hide the view here
            sba.put(position, false); // reset the click if required
         }
}
```